# Change perforce workspace view map from commandline

Tags: perforce, workspace

I have searched the internet and the perforce help pages, but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

In a script, so on the commandline, I want to change my workspace view map. For example:

//depot/some/branch/myfolder/mysubfolder/... /home/myuser/perforce/branch/myfolder/myworkspace/...
to
//depot/some/branch/... /home/myuser/perforce/branch/...

I cannot figure out what command to use. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use the `p4 client` command.  You can script that using the `-i` and `-o` options, which let you interact with the workspace form via STDIN and STDOUT.

An easier path is using a scripting API like P4Python:

```
cspec = p4.fetch_client('my_ws_name')
view = ["//depot/some/branch/... /home/myuser/perforce/branch/..."]
cspec["View"] = view
p4.save_client(cspec)
```